# How can I turn off fast running on the Smart Moving mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

We have smart moving installed on my server. It has a feature that if you press 'O' or 'I' you move speed can be increased by a percentage. I've tested this and I've moved across the map at 3000%+ the normal speed of moving. Because we feel this is a way to cheat, I've decided that I want to turn this off on our server.

I've looked all over the smart moving config file for my server. I see two sections:

- Standard Sprinting (Vanilla Minecraft's implementation)
- Generic Sprinting (Smart Moving's implementation)

Here is content for those sections:

```
# =====================================================================
# Standard sprinting
# ------------------
# Below you find the options for standard vanilla Minecraft sprinting
# (sometimes referred as "running" here)
# =====================================================================

# To switch on/off standard sprinting
move.run:true

# Standard sprinting factor (>= 1.1)
move.run.factor:1.3

# To switch on/off standard sprinting exhaustion
move.run.exhaustion:false;h:true


# Maximum exhaustion to start a standard sprint (>= 0)
move.exhaustion.run.start:75

# Maximum exhaustion to continue a standard sprint (>= "move.exhaustion.run.start")
move.exhaustion.run.stop:100

# Exhaustion gain factor while standard sprinting (>= 0)
move.exhaustion.run.gain.factor:1.5




# =====================================================================
# Generic sprinting
# -----------------
# Below you find the options for Smart Moving's generic sprinting
# available for many different smart movings plus standard walking
# =====================================================================

# To switch on/off generic sprinting
move.sprint:false

# Generic sprinting factor (>= 1.1 AND >= 'move.run.factor' + 0.1 if relevant)
move.sprint.factor:1.5

# To switch on/off sprinting exhaustion
#! Interpreted value "true" is ignored because the default value of property "move.sprint" is "false" !#
move.sprint.exhaustion:true;e:false
```

As you can see, I've turned SM's sprinting off but it doesn't seem to prevent the ability to increase your speed. Do you know what setting I should be changing?

Answer (score 3):

To turn off the speed keys set `move.speed.user` to `false` in your configuration:

```
move.speed.user:false
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work with the server. It only works if the client has that setting. I want to be able to override the setting from the server to prevent people from using the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Right at the bottom of the server side config file is an option to use server settings or use user side settings. Change that and it will over-ride the user configuration.